# Newline character \n is not working in shell on Mac OSX with sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have to add a new line in the existing csv at the specific line number.
I am using following command

```
sed -i '' '3i\
Line to add in csv\n' data.csv
```

But it is adding the line as 
Line to add in csv**n**

Comment: GNU `sed` recognizes `\n` as a newline; BSD `sed` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell `\n` has no particular meaning, it just means *literal n*. Instead:

```
sed -i '' '3i\
Line to add in csv\
' data.csv
```

Comment: Same response a bit before ;)

Comment: @GillesQuenot I just spent an extra second too long testing it!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use :

```
sed -i '' '3i\
Line to add in csv\
' data.csv
```

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is not good for using `\n`, [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) handle this better with the same syntax most of the time than [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) Ex :

```
perl -i -pe 's///' file
```

(for substitutions)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [ed](/questions/tagged/ed) command for fun ([sed](/questions/tagged/sed) ancestor):

### File :

```
$ cat file
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

### [ed](/questions/tagged/ed) command :

```
$ ed -s file<<EOF
3i
Line to add in csv
.
wq
EOF
```

### Edited file :

```
$ cat file
a
b
Line to add in csv
c
d
e
f
```